# If $f$ is differentiable at $c$ then $F$ is differentiable at $c$

Tags: calculus, continuity, proof-writing, indefinite-integrals

I've be having trouble with this question and am looking for some advice.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R},  a  <  b$.   Let $f$ be  an  integrable  function  on  $[a, b]$,  let $c \in(a, b)$, and let
$$F(x) =\int_0^x \ f(t)\,dt.$$ Prove or disprove the following:

If $f$ is differentiable at $c$ then $F$ is differentiable at $c$.

Answer (score 6):

By the first fundamental theorem of calculus, $F'(c)=f(c)$. So in fact we don't even need $f$ to be differentiable at $c$; it is enough for $f$ to be continuous at $c$.